# Let $V$ be a representation of $G$ with dim($V$)=2. Show that $V$ is reducible if and only if ...

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be a representation of $G$ with dim($V$)=2.

Show that $V$ is reducible if and only if there is some $v \in V$ such that there for each $g \in G$ exists a $\lambda_{g} \in \mathbb{C}$ with $gv=\lambda_{g}v$.

I don't know how to show this.. Anyone who can help?

Comment: What are non-trivial invariant subspaces going to look like..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V$ is reducible is equivalent to saying that there exists a proper invariant subset $U$which has dimension $1$ here since $dim(V)=2$. Let $v$ be a basis of $U$, for every $g\in G, g.v\in U$ is equivalent to the fact that there exists $\lambda_g$ such that $g.v=\lambda_gv$.